# Find a linear system whose solution is given by W= span({3, 1, 2, 4), (1, 2, 1, 1)})

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

How would I go about solving this type of problem? Because no particular is shown, can I assume that the solution can be homogenous. But still how would I set up this equation to be solved?

I know that the solution of the system is for some x and y:
x(3, 2, 1, 4) + y(1, 2, 1, 1) but how is the matrix and stuff set up?